# Error while merging different branches

Tags: git, git-merge

I just run the command:

`git merge branch2`

Then git found a conflict and asked me nicely to solve it, so I did.
After solving the conflict problem I tried to run:

`git commit`

and I got this:

```
$ git commit
error: cannot spawn emacs: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor 'emacs'
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

My terminal is like this right now:
`User@User-PC MINGW64 /x/myPath (branch|MERGING)`

So the merge isn't done yet, right ? How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `-m` flag which is used to display a message for the commit and every commit needs to have a message.

For example:

```
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Comment: Ohh, I know `-m`. But I thought that only `git commit` would be enough to just tell git that the conflict is solved.